# Problem with getting json with jQuery from api written in flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am very new to web programming and is trying to a simple web app.
I have written a rest api with flask:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    global data
    response = {'data': data.to_dict(orient='records')}
    return make_response(jsonify(response), 200)
```

The data variable is a pandas dataframe.
This returned ok when I tried to access it from the web browser.
So after this, I tried to write an html to make a jQuery call with script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    th{ 
        color:#fff;
            }
</style>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
        
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:5000', function(response) {
  myArray = response.data;
  console.log(myArray);
  buildTable(myArray);
})
    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].age}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].email}</td>
                      </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }
</script>
```

When I tried to open the html file in the browser, the console does not log anything and no error message was given. Its just that the table is not rendering. Am I using the jQuery call correctly?

Comment: Hi, not even `console.log(myArray);` gets printed ?

Comment: use + symbol for concatenation $ is considering here as a serverside variable.

Comment: use  "<td>"+data[i].name+"</td>" pattern instead of  <td>${data[i].name}</td>

Comment: also call $.getJSON in document.ready

Comment: See there is a request or not in network tab in debugging tool(F12).

Comment: @Swati, no nothing is outputting in the console

Comment: @seongkukhan, I did see a request in the debugging tool and also the correct data is being returned and shown in the response. Also I am seeing the request shown in my terminal where my flask program is running. However the table is not being built.

Comment: It's weird. I copied that code into my editor. and I did test. A log has been printed. you're sure that your log levels in ur browser?

Comment: My bad, the api gave one of the values as a nan, thats whats causing the problem. Thanks for all of your help!